# Filtering Microsoft Access Subform

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a subform populated with different tasks. I want to filter them on `DUE_DT` with a filter that happens automatically. Some of the records have a blank `DUE_DT`, which I would like to filer out. I would also like to filter out records whose `DUE_DT` is more than 30 days past. I tried using VB but I haven't been able to find the appropriate syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"I want to filter them on DUE_DT with a filter that happens automatically."*

I'm not quite sure what you have in mind there, but I wonder whether that could be handled by a `WHERE` clause in the subform's record source query.

```
WHERE DUE_DT >= Date() - 30
```

That would be automatic in the sense that the filter would always apply.

Note you don't have to add another condition to explicitly exclude Nulls (such as `DUE_DT Is Not Null`) because Null is not `>= Date() - 30`.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion in the Record Source Query, and when I run the query, I am getting the results I need.

However, when I open the form in Form View, the subform outputs the same results, as if the query is not being used at all. Do you have any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: When you run that query, you get the results you need.  That sounds correct to me, so I don't understand ... hmm ... when you said record source query, did you mean the record source of the main form or the subform?  I meant the subform's record source.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see the option to edit the record source query for the subform.

Comment: Close the main form.  Open the subform by itself in Design View.  Then adjust its record source property.

Comment: Thank you so much -you're an absolute lifesaver. Much like a life jacket to a man lost at sea.

Answer (score 3):

Here is some syntax for appplying a filter to a sub form:

```
Forms!MyMainForm.ASubFormOnMyMainForm.Form.Filter = "whatever your filter is"
Forms!MyMainForm.ASubFormOnMyMainForm.Form.FilterOn = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in VBA, should work on every form or module you put it in:

```
Form_subFormName.Filter = "DUE_DT IS NOT NULL AND DUE_DT >= #" & (Date - 30) & "#"
Form_subFormName.FilterOn = True
```

Replace the `subFormName` in `Form_subFormName` with the name of your subform, but keep the `Form_`.

Comment: I'm struggling to make this work -are `[Form]` and `[subFormName]` supposed to be changed with the name of this form/subform?