# Form with multiple subforms - synchronize record change of subforms

Tags: ms-access

I have a form (F_ptselect) with multiple subforms (F_s1, F_s2, F_s3). On the main form I have a combo box that allows me to choose an integer identifier (i.e., ID = 1001, id = 1002, id = 1003, id = 1004, etc.). The subforms are also all linked by ID using "Link Master Fields" and "Link Child Fields". I've found and modified vba that allows me to choose an ID (say 1001) from the combo box on F_ptselect, and subsequently pull up all the data for ID = 1001 on F_s1, F_s2, and F_s3.

Here's that vba:

```
Private Sub find_ID_AfterUpdate()
' Find the record that matches the control.
Dim rs As Object

Set rs = Me.Recordset.Clone
rs.FindFirst "[ID] = " & Me![find_ID] & ""
If Not rs.EOF Then Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
End Sub
```

Now, for each ID there are multiple records (i.e., ID=1001 and day=1, ID=1001 and day=2, ID=1002 and day=1, ID=1002 and day=2 etc.). I'd like to be able to have a combo box or button or something that allows me to synchronize the ability to cycle through these records of a single ID. So if I select ID 1001 from the F_ptselect combo box, I'd like to see F_s1, F_s2, and F_s3 for ID 1001, day 1. Then I'd like to be able to change to day 2 for ID 1001 quickly using a combo box selection, button or something. Currently, I'd have to go to the record arrows at the bottom of each subform to change the record. Each row of data has a primary key (let's call it KEY) as well. So a query row or table row would look like:

| KEY | ID | Day |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1001 | 1 |
| 2 | 1001 | 2 |
| 3 | 1002 | 1 |
| 4 | 1002 | 2 |

Comment: I expect could use parameterized query for each subform RecordSource or code that sets each subform Filter property.

Comment: Hi June7, any chance you could provide an example? I'm trying my best to learn VBA but am still quite new.

Comment: Do research. Should be plenty of examples. Start with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17949586/filtering-microsoft-access-subform

Comment: Maybe this article of mine can help you: [Synchronizing Multiple Subforms in Access](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/18107/Synchronizing-Multiple-Subforms-in-Access.html?preview=cUa6D5QxDFA%3D).

Comment: June7 - I've been looking for answers for hours and came here as a last resort. I will take a look at the filtering you've suggested. Gustav - I did come across your article, but it seemed a little too complicated at first. I'm trying it now though and hopefully it will work! Thanks

Comment: Gustav - The SyncSubforms 1.2.0.zip doesn't seem to work for me. I updated the txtSyncSubforms to contain [PPAsubFreight]![ID1] rather than [PPAsubFreight]![txt ID1]. Otherwise the txtSyncSubforms is showing "#Name?" in View mode. The records are no longer synced when changing. 

I also am not usre which part of the VBA I should edit to reflect my own ID variables and forms. Could you possibly point me in the right direction on this so that I can find the right names to replace?

Comment: Are these subforms bound to different tables? Are tables identical structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Options:

1. RecordsetClone/Bookmark method for each subform
   applied by Gustav sample Access db in https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/18107/Synchronizing-Multiple-Subforms-in-Access.html?preview=cUa6D5QxDFA%3D
2. set each subform Filter and FilterOn properties
3. parameterized query as RecordSource for each subform

I always name subform container different from the form it holds, like `ctrFS1`. For option 2, consider:

```
Sub cbxDay_AfterUpdate()
Dim strF As String
With Me
strF = "[Day]=" & .cbxDay
.ctrFS1.Form.Filter = strF
.ctrFS1.Form.FilterOn = True
.ctrFS2.Form.Filter = strF
.ctrFS2.Form.FilterOn = True
.ctrFS3.Form.Filter = strF
.ctrFS3.Form.FilterOn = True
End With
End Sub
```

If you name each subform container like: ctrFS1, ctrFS2, ctrFS3, consider:

```
Dim x As Integer
With Me
For x = 1 to 3
    .Controls("ctrFS" & x).Form.Filter = "Day=" & .cbxDay
    .Controls("ctrFS" & x).Form.FilterOn = True
Next
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the final code (based on the answer from June7) for any interested. The "Day" field is actually a string in my tables so that's why the concatenation syntax is for a string.

```
Private Sub find_day_AfterUpdate()
Dim strF1 As String
With Me
strF1 = "[Day]='" & .find_day & "'"
.F_s1.Form.Filter = strF1
.F_s1.Form.FilterOn = True
End With

Dim strF2 As String
With Me
strF2 = "[Day]='" & .find_day & "'"
.F_s2.Form.Filter = strF2
.F_s2.Form.FilterOn = True
End With

Dim strF3 As String
With Me
strF3 = "[Day]='" & .find_day & "'"
.F_s3.Form.Filter = strF3
.F_s3.Form.FilterOn = True
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You don't need multiple string variables - one will do and all can be within one With block, as in my example.